# identify records in one dataset that are in between times in another data set

Tags: r, gpx

I have GPX data in one data frame and another data frame I'm calling info_access with other information that I would like to "merge" with the GPX data.  The data frames do not have a common varialbe between them.  I would like to use the TowStartDate, InclinometerStart (time),TowEndDate and InclinometerEnd (time) columns in the second data frame (info_access) to identify rows in the GPX data frame where the date/time are between the TowStartDate& InclinometerStart and the TowEndDate & InclinometerEnd.  I would then like to assign those GPX times the Tow value from the second data frame.  The GPX data sets are large so I am running into issues with the way I was originally trying to do this.

Example GPX data:

```
example_gpx<-data.frame(Long=c(-70.92108,-70.92108,-70.92108, -70.92108, -70.92108 ),
    Lat=c(41.64437,41.64437,41.64437 ,41.64437,41.64437),
    Date=c("2016-06-04","2016-06-04","2016-06-04","2016-06-04","2016-06-04"),
    Time=c("19:15:08","19:15:09","19:15:10","19:15:11","19:15:12"))
```

Example info_access

```
example_access<-structure(list(Tow = 201604001:201604005, TowStartDate = structure(c(1465012800, 
1465012800, 1465012800, 1465012800, 1465012800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TowEndDate = structure(c(1465012800, 
1465012800, 1465012800, 1465012800, 1465012800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), InclinometerStart = c("14:06:00", "15:05:00", 
"15:51:20", "16:52:10", "17:27:50"), InclinometerEnd = c("14:22:10", 
"15:20:20", "16:06:20", "17:07:00", "17:43:00"), date_time_start = c("2016-06-04 14:06:00", 
"2016-06-04 15:05:00", "2016-06-04 15:51:20", "2016-06-04 16:52:10", 
"2016-06-04 17:27:50"), date_time_end = c("2016-06-04 14:22:10", 
"2016-06-04 15:20:20", "2016-06-04 16:06:20", "2016-06-04 17:07:00", 
"2016-06-04 17:43:00")), .Names = c("Tow", "TowStartDate", "TowEndDate", 
"InclinometerStart", "InclinometerEnd", "date_time_start", "date_time_end"
), row.names = 181:185, class = "data.frame")
```

I have been trying to use `expand.grid` to create a data set with all combinations of Tow number from the info access dataset and all times from the gpx dataset.  I am running into issues with memory size because my original datasets are large.

Example code to identify date/times in example_gpx in example_access:

```
#use expand.grid function 
Tow<-unique( example_access$Tow)
Time<-example_gpx$Time

a<-expand.grid(Tow,Time)
names(a)<-c("Tow","Time")
head(a)

b<-merge(a,example_gpx,"Time")
head(b)
length(b[,1])

c<-merge(b,example_access,by="Tow")
head(c)
str(c)
length(b[,1])

head(c)

        Tow     Time      Long      Lat       Date TowStartDate TowEndDate
1 201604001 19:15:09 -70.92108 41.64437 2016-06-04   2016-06-04 2016-06-04
2 201604001 19:15:08 -70.92108 41.64437 2016-06-04   2016-06-04 2016-06-04
3 201604001 19:15:10 -70.92108 41.64437 2016-06-04   2016-06-04 2016-06-04
4 201604001 19:15:12 -70.92108 41.64437 2016-06-04   2016-06-04 2016-06-04
5 201604001 19:15:11 -70.92108 41.64437 2016-06-04   2016-06-04 2016-06-04
6 201604002 19:15:12 -70.92108 41.64437 2016-06-04   2016-06-04 2016-06-04
  InclinometerStart InclinometerEnd     date_time_start       date_time_end
1          14:06:00        14:22:10 2016-06-04 14:06:00 2016-06-04 14:22:10
2          14:06:00        14:22:10 2016-06-04 14:06:00 2016-06-04 14:22:10
3          14:06:00        14:22:10 2016-06-04 14:06:00 2016-06-04 14:22:10
4          14:06:00        14:22:10 2016-06-04 14:06:00 2016-06-04 14:22:10
5          14:06:00        14:22:10 2016-06-04 14:06:00 2016-06-04 14:22:10
6          15:05:00        15:20:20 2016-06-04 15:05:00 2016-06-04 15:20:20
```

This works in my small example, but if anyone has ideas about how to do this with a GPX file with 88,287 observations it would be helpful or a more elegant solution it would be helpful.

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.3     gmt_1.2-0       RODBC_1.3-12    lubridate_1.5.0
[5] rgdal_1.0-6     maptools_0.8-36 sp_1.1-1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.6     lattice_0.20-31 assertthat_0.1  grid_3.2.1     
 [5] R6_2.1.0        DBI_0.3.1       magrittr_1.5    stringi_0.5-5  
 [9] tools_3.2.1     stringr_1.0.0   foreign_0.8-63  parallel_3.2.1 
>
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but it does not look like you have any gpx observations that fit in the access intervals. All of the gpx times are 19:00... and the latest inclinometerend is 17:00... Is your method working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with using the `lubridate` package. Note that I changed your example data so that the intervals lined up and it would actually be able to assign Tow values to the GPX data. The `example_access` is unchanged.

```
library(lubridate)

example_gpx<-data.frame(Long=c(-70.92108,-70.92108,-70.92108, -70.92108, -70.92108 ),
                        Lat=c(41.64437,41.64437,41.64437 ,41.64437,41.64437),
                        Date=c("2016-06-04","2016-06-04","2016-06-04","2016-06-04","2016-06-04"),
                        Time=c("14:15:08","15:15:09","15:59:10","17:06:11","17:30:12"))

example_access$date_time_start<-ymd_hms(example_access$date_time_start)
example_access$date_time_end<-ymd_hms(example_access$date_time_end)

example_gpx$date_time<-paste(example_gpx$Date, example_gpx$Time)
example_gpx$date_time<-ymd_hms(example_gpx$date_time)

example_gpx$Tow<-sapply(1:nrow(example_gpx), function(x)
  if(example_gpx[x,]$date_time %between%  
     c(example_access[x,]$date_time_start,example_access[x,]$date_time_end)) example_access[x,]$Tow
      else NA)

example_gpx

Long   Lat       Date     Time           date_time       Tow
-70.92 41.64 2016-06-04 14:15:08 2016-06-04 14:15:08 201604001
-70.92 41.64 2016-06-04 15:15:09 2016-06-04 15:15:09 201604002
-70.92 41.64 2016-06-04 15:59:10 2016-06-04 15:59:10 201604003
-70.92 41.64 2016-06-04 17:06:11 2016-06-04 17:06:11 201604004
-70.92 41.64 2016-06-04 17:30:12 2016-06-04 17:30:12 201604005
```

This method may or may not work if you have missing or messy data.

**Edit:** The above method will only work if your two data sets are lined up with each other, which is almost certainly *not* the case. The code below will work regardless of if the two sets are lined up, however, it may be a little slower, but I think that the robustness is worth it:

```
    library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

example_gpx<-data.frame(Long=c(-70.92108,-70.92108,-70.92108, -70.92108, -70.92108 ),
                        Lat=c(41.64437,41.64437,41.64437 ,41.64437,41.64437),
                        Date=c("2016-06-04","2016-06-04","2016-06-04","2016-06-04","2016-06-04"),
                        Time=c("14:15:08","15:15:09","15:59:10","17:06:11","17:30:12"))

example_access$date_time_start<-ymd_hms(example_access$date_time_start)
example_access$date_time_end<-ymd_hms(example_access$date_time_end)

example_gpx$date_time<-paste(example_gpx$Date, example_gpx$Time)
example_gpx$date_time<-ymd_hms(example_gpx$date_time)

example_gpx$Tow<-NA

for(x in 1:nrow(example_access)){
  example_gpx[which(example_gpx$date_time %between% 
                      c(example_access[x,]$date_time_start,
                        example_access[x,]$date_time_end)),]$Tow<-example_access[x,]$Tow
}
example_gpx

Long   Lat       Date     Time           date_time       Tow
-70.92 41.64 2016-06-04 14:15:08 2016-06-04 14:15:08 201604001
-70.92 41.64 2016-06-04 15:15:09 2016-06-04 15:15:09 201604002
-70.92 41.64 2016-06-04 15:59:10 2016-06-04 15:59:10 201604003
-70.92 41.64 2016-06-04 17:06:11 2016-06-04 17:06:11 201604004
-70.92 41.64 2016-06-04 17:30:12 2016-06-04 17:30:12 201604005
```

Comment: Hi - Sorry I have been out of the office.  Your code worked on the example dataset after you corrected the times.  When I run it on my large dataset I get the following error message:Error in if (info_gpx[x, ]$Date_time %between% c(info_access[x, ]$date_time_start,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.  Do you think this is because the data are messy?

Comment: actually, I think `%between%` comes from the `data.table` package. Try `library(data.table)` and see if that works. Also, be sure to install `data.table` if you have not done so already.

Comment: See the edited code I just added. It should work much better than the previous answer

Comment: Sorry now I am getting a different error message: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Tow", value = 201605018L) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0.

Comment: Did you run `example_gpx$Tow<-NA` before the `for` loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116501/discussion-between-bryan-goggin-and-user41509).

Comment: Just saw your message and am in the chat.